# MYSQL Select with joins and where

Tags: mysql, select, join, where-clause

I got two tables:

**device**

```
deviceID

deviceName

categoryID
```

**category**

```
categoryID

categoryName
```

It seems that I am really to stupid to solve my problem; I need a select query that brings me this as a result:

**resultTable**

```
deviceID

categoryID

categoryName
```

I tried something like this, but no success:

```
SELECT deviceID
    , categoryID
    , categoryName
FROM category
LEFT JOIN device ON (category.categoryID = device.categoryID)
WHERE deviceID = '1';
```

In short, I need a table which shows me the categorie's ID and name, of the category a **certain** device is in.

Hope you get me, since my English is not good.

Comment: The only problem I see with your query is that `categoryID` in the `select` is ambiguous.  Using table aliases may fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT D.DEVICEID,
       C.CATEGORYID,
       C.CATEGORYNAME
FROM DEVICE D
INNER JOIN CATEGORY C
ON C.CATEGORYID = D.CATEGORYID
WHERE D.DEVICEID = 1
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. To be honest I've been dealing with this problem for hours now, finally my php script works! THXTHX